# REALM: preload RealmObjects

Tags: android, realm

Is there any way to pre-load `RealmObject`s or `RealmList` or `RealmResult`s? Like to read em from the database and store it in memory. As far as I know Realm does not store actual data in class object's fields. But I need the data to be stored at least in memory.

Lets say I have a big `RealmObject` that has multiple `RealmObject`s linked. At some time I have to iterate over these children and read some of their fields. It would cause a little more lag than simply reading the values from RAM. At some time I might need to iterate over these values in the UI Thread.

I have read about `RealmResults.load()` but I didn't really understand the mechanics behind it. Does it actually preload the data?

Thanks.

Comment: Realm is using mmap in the underlying storage engine to map db file to memory. It means when you access the same data twice, the data has already been loaded to the memory if the kernel doesn't swipe them away. The problem is java needs to load data from java heap, so the data has to be loaded from native heap to java heap every time. A suggestion is if you really have some super hot data needs to access all the time, maybe you can consider to use `RealmObject.copyFromRealm()` that will create a standalone object and data is in java heap. But the object won't be managed by Realm anymore.

Comment: Great! Thats what I need. I don't really care about my `RealmObject` being managed by Realm since I have to copy it to memory just to bind the data to the GUI once. 

I'd like to get more info on this issue. What happens if I bind a `RealmChangeListener` to a `RealmObject` then I detach it from `Realm`? I guess the callback will be called upon change as `Realm.copyFromRealm` will return a different object. Right?

Also I'd like to understand what `RealmResults.load()` actually does but that's another question I guess.

Comment: `RealmObject.copyFromRealm()` will return a new object, and the old one stays the same. But since the standalone object is not managed by Realm anymore, its data won't be auto-updated. `RealmResults.load()` has nothing to do with this, it is related with async query. It **tries** to run/load the async query by blocking the current thread if the query has not been finished yet.

Comment: @beeender Alright, thank you very much for clarifications! Now how do I accept your comment as an answer? Or should I answer it myself? upd: nvm googled it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above by *beeender*:

> Realm is using mmap in the underlying storage engine to map db file to
>   memory. It means when you access the same data twice, the data has
>   already been loaded to the memory if the kernel doesn't swipe them
>   away. The problem is java needs to load data from java heap, so the
>   data has to be loaded from native heap to java heap every time. A
>   suggestion is if you really have some super hot data needs to access
>   all the time, maybe you can consider to use
>   `RealmObject.copyFromRealm()` that will create a standalone object and
>   data is in java heap. But the object won't be managed by Realm anymore